# Is it better to arrange datatypes in a computer programme using arrays or linked lists?

Tags: data-structures

How should datatypes be organised in a computer programme? Is it better to utilise arrays or linked lists? I'm not sure what the difference is, but I seem to recall hearing that arrays are quicker. Or perhaps it was connected lists? So, which one should I go with?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)#Implementations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Implementation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure)#Comparison_with_other_data_structures

Comment: I suggest you learn what the difference is first. And you implement something with both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Data structures are not chosen "randomly" and there is no absolute preference order.

For a given application, different data structure options can be compared. In particular, for containers or associative containers, one looks at the time and space complexities of insertions, deletions, lookups..., put in relation to what the application will effectively require.

So saying "arrays are quicker" makes little sense. Your question sounds like "is a hammer better than a screwdriver, I heard that they are heavier"?

Answer (score -2):

Whether to use arrays or linked lists to arrange data types in a computer program depends on the specific requirements and characteristics of the program.

Arrays are a good choice when the data size is fixed and known in advance, and when random access to elements is required. They are also more memory efficient than linked lists for small data sets, and the elements of an array are stored in contiguous memory locations, which can result in faster access times.

Linked lists, on the other hand, are a better choice when the data size is not fixed and when frequent insertions or deletions are required. They can be more memory efficient than arrays for large data sets because they only allocate memory for the elements that are actually used, and can be resized dynamically as needed. Linked lists are also useful when elements need to be inserted or deleted frequently, as they can be modified more easily than arrays.

Therefore, the choice between arrays and linked lists depends on the specific requirements of the program. If you need fast access to elements and the size of the data set is known in advance, use an array. If the size of the data set is not fixed and frequent insertions or deletions are required, use a linked list.

Comment: Arrays also have better data locality, which can result in better cache performance if they are being accessed coherently.

Comment: Did you use AI or ChatGPT to help you with writing this answer?  If so, please [edit] your answer to provide proper attribution for the source of this material.  This is required by Stack Exchange rules.

Comment: And it’s not really good advice, independent of looking like produced by some text interpolation engine.